# Issues in a Bash loop that processes a large delimited file

Tags: bash, grep

I have to find out if a job in production has an accompanying job in backup. The area of the job is denoted by the suffix, PS for production, PP for backup. Moreover, I need to ensure that not just the names are the same (except for last two characters), but that the scripts that they reference are the same as well.

I used a double while loop. I echoed out the contents and all the data lines up, the captured greps, the echo into the while loop. the script data is good until I get to the if statements, where I extrapolate the script name and then compare them to each other.  When I run the jobs I can see which ones don't line up, however, I need these if statements to do the work for me. There are over 24,000 jobs in Autosys, and the split between Production and backup is slight, but even slight is considerable. This is too much to do by manually checking off a spreadsheet.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,

file="/tmp/casper_test.txt"

while read -r area job machine script
do
    prod_line=$(grep  ${job%??} $file)
    echo "$prod_line" | while IFS=, read -r area job machine script
    do
        if [ "$area" == "PROD" ] ; then
            prod_script="$script"
        elif [ "$area" == "BACKUP" ] ; then
            backup_script="$script"

        elif [ "$prod_script" == "$backup_script" ] ; then
            echo "MATCH,$area,$job,$machine,$script "
        else
            echo "NO MATCH,$area,$job, $machine, $script "
        fi
    done
done < $file
```

input file `/tmp/casper_test.txt`:

```
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_01_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
PROD, CAPSER_JOB_01_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_02_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script02'
PROD, CAPSER_JOB_02_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/comeAndPlay'
BACKUP, CAPSER_03_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script03'
PROD, CAPSER_JOB_03_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script03'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_04_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script04'
PROD, CAPSER_JOB_04_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/withUsDanny'
PROD, CAPSER_JOB_05_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script05'
PROD, CAPSER_JOB_06_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script06'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_07_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
PROD, CAPSER_JOB_07_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in pure Bash with hashes and a single read from the input file.  With 24K lines in your input file, this approach will be much more efficient than your solution which reads the file **n+1** times, that 24001 times for your file that has 24K lines!  I have added some basic error handling as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
line=0
declare -A prod_jobs_job prod_jobs_scripts prod_jobs_machines backup_jobs_scripts
while IFS=, read -r area job machine script; do
    ((line++))
    j="${job%??}"
    if [[ $area == "PROD" ]]; then
      prod_jobs_job[$j]="$job"           # this hash holds the original job name
      prod_jobs_scripts[$j]="$script"    # holds the prod script
      prod_jobs_machines[$j]="$machine"  # holds the prod machine, used for printing only
    elif [[ $area == "BACKUP" ]]; then
      backup_jobs_scripts[$j]="$script"  # holds the backup script, used for comparison
    else
      printf '%s\n' "Unknown area '$area' at line number $line" >&2
    fi
done < <(sed 's/, */,/g' t1) # make sure to strip out the spaces after commas

# traverse the prod jobs hash and compare with backup
# if there is no match in backup hash, treat it as an error
for j in "${!prod_jobs_scripts[@]}"; do
    prod_script="${prod_jobs_scripts[$j]}"
    job="${prod_jobs_job[$j]}"
    backup_script="${backup_jobs_scripts[$j]}"
    [[ ! $backup_script ]] && { printf '%s\n' "No backup job for '$job'" >&1; continue; }
    prod_machine="${prod_jobs_machines[$j]}"
    if [[ $prod_script == $backup_script ]]; then
      printf '%s\n' "MATCH:PROD,$job,$prod_machine,$prod_script"
    else
      printf '%s\n' "NO MATCH:PROD,$job,$prod_machine,$prod_script"
    fi
done
```

For your input file, we get this output:

```
MATCH:PROD,CAPSER_JOB_07_PS,usa-penguin.com,/bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
No backup job for 'CAPSER_JOB_06_PS'
MATCH:PROD,CAPSER_JOB_01_PS,usa-penguin.com,/bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
NO MATCH:PROD,CAPSER_JOB_02_PS,usa-penguin.com,/bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/comeAndPlay'
No backup job for 'CAPSER_JOB_03_PS'
NO MATCH:PROD,CAPSER_JOB_04_PS,usa-penguin.com,/bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/withUsDanny'
No backup job for 'CAPSER_JOB_05_PS'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since all you really need is the list of production job names without a matching backup job, here's an awk script that lists them:

```
awk -F ', *' '{gsub("_..$", "", $2)} /BACKUP/{b[$2] = $NF} /PROD/{p[$2] = $NF} END {for (i in p) if (p[i] != b[i]) print i}'
```

- `-F ', *'` - split on commas followed by spaces
- `{gsub("_..$", "", $2)}` remove the suffix from the job name, the second field
- `/BACKUP/{b[$2] = $NF} /PROD/{p[$2]=$NF}` save backup scripts in one array and prod scripts in another
- `END {for (i in p) if (p[i] != b[i]) print i}` - after reading all lines, loop through prod scripts and print ones without a matching script in backup

Example output:

```
CAPSER_JOB_02
CAPSER_JOB_03
CAPSER_JOB_04
CAPSER_JOB_05
CAPSER_JOB_06
```

Jobs with these IDs were all not matched, and the rest had matches.

As for the shell script, look at what happens in the inner while loop:

```
echo "$prod_line" | while IFS=, read -r area job machine script
do
    if [ "$area" == "PROD" ] ; then
        prod_script="$script"
    elif [ "$area" == "BACKUP" ] ; then
        backup_script="$script"

    elif [ "$prod_script" == "$backup_script" ] ; then
        echo "MATCH,$area,$job,$machine,$script "
    else
        echo "NO MATCH,$area,$job, $machine, $script "
    fi
done
```

There are never more than two lines in the `grep` output, and those have either `BACKUP` or `PROD` in them. Thus your third `elif` and `else` are never reached. Those should probably be moved outside the inner loop, so that the testing happens when you have read both. And since some backup jobs are missing, you might want to clear the values before reading them, so that old values are not reused.

Comment: The `awk` solution is nifty.  Nitpick: it is missing the possibility of not having a backup job.  Mismatch is not same as missing.

Answer (score 0):

## update

Trying another option:

```
grep PROD /tmp/casper.txt > PROD.txt
grep BACKUP /tmp/casper.txt > BACKUP.txt

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$6];b[substr($2,0,13)];next}($6 in a && substr($2,0,13) in b){print}' BACKUP.txt PROD.txt
```

This will result in and will be sustainable for a large number of lines in the input file....

```
 PROD, CAPSER_JOB_01_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
 PROD, CAPSER_JOB_07_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
```

## NOTE

The code below is not sustainable for larger input files.

You made the `while loop` overly complicated, and kinda wrong by using the same variables names for both loops. See if the following works for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,
file="casper.txt"
while read -r area job machine script
do
    if [ "$area" == "PROD" ] ; then
        prod_script="$script"
        jobname=${job%??}
        IFS=,
        while read -r area1 job1 machine1 script1
        do
            if [ "$area1" == "BACKUP" ]; then
            jobname1=${job1%??}
                if [ "$jobname" == "$jobname1" ]; then
                    if [ "$prod_script" == "$script1" ] ; then
                        echo "MATCH: $area,$job,$machine,$script"
                        break;
                    fi
                fi
            fi
        done < "$file"
    fi
done < "$file"
```

This will result from your input file,

```
]# ./casper
MATCH: PROD, CAPSER_JOB_01_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
MATCH: PROD, CAPSER_JOB_07_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
```

Comment: It's good you pointed out the issue in OP's code.  However, you didn't seem to have noticed the inefficiency.  This one reads the input file 24001 times!  That is n+1 times where n is the number of lines in the input file.

Comment: huh! How is your code efficient with a `while loop` and a `for loop` ? and for that you are downvoting... jeez..

Comment: My solution reads the file only once.  Looping through the hash is very efficient as it is in memory.  @muru's `awk` solution reads the file once as well.  Yes, I had to downvote for your I/O issue, sorry.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize he had 24k lines in there... This solution clearly is not sustainable.

Comment: Added another solution with `awk` along with a note about the `while loop` code.